# Math mode in table headers (tabularx)

Tags: tables, math-mode, tabularx

I am editing a document, using a custom class. The author has numbers with a bar over them in a table header, e.g. `$0.58\bar3$`. However, when I try to compile it I get the following errors:

```
! Package amsmath Error: \bar allowed only in math mode.
! Missing $ inserted.
! Missing } inserted.
```

I have checked and double-checked and I am not actually missing a $ or }. If I comment out the line with `\bar` everything is fine.

Is there a secret to using math mode in a table?

ETA: An attempt at an MWE –

```
\documentclass{socsci}
\let\footnote=\endnote
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{input-symbols  = {()},
     group-digits       = false}

\usepackage{epstopdf}
\DeclareGraphicsRule{.tif}{png}{.png}{`convert #1 `basename #1 .tif`.png}
\widowpenalty10000
\clubpenalty10000
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{changepage}

\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\makeatletter 
\g@addto@macro{\UrlBreaks}{\do\/\do\-} 
\makeatother
\newcommand\fignote[1]{\captionsetup{font=footnotesize}\caption*{#1}}
\setlength\multlinegap{0pt} %For multi-line equations that are aligned to left margin

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning,calc,decorations.pathmorphing,backgrounds,fit,petri,automata} 
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization.formats.functions}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{natbib}

\tikzset{
 state/.style={
 rectangle,
 rounded corners,
 draw=black, very thick,
 minimum height=2em,minimum width=2cm,
 inner sep=2pt,
 text centered,
 },
}


\newcommand*{\LargerCdot}{\raisebox{-0.25ex}{\scalebox{1.2}{$\cdot$}}}


\begin{document}

%tab6
\begin{table*}[t!]
\begin{adjustwidth}{-1.5in}{}
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Network density.}
 \label{tab6}
\centering
\footnotesize
\begin{tabularx}{6.5in}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}l*5{d{2.2}}} 
\toprule
Density & $\leq 0.50$ & $0.58\bar3$ & $0.66\bar6$ & $0.750$ & $>0.75$ \\ \midrule \addlinespace
 & \% & \% & \% & \% & \% \\
Disconnected & 16.27 & 0.23 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
Weak & 26.61 & 0.70 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
Unilateral & 51.45 & 51.98 & 15.76 & 2.80 & 0 \\
Strong & 5.67 & 47.09 & 84.24 & 97.20 & \ccell{100} \\ \midrule \addlinespace
Total \% & \ccell{100} & \ccell{100} & \ccell{100} & \ccell{100} & \ccell{100} \\
Total n & \ccell{25,376} & \ccell{27,456} & \ccell{7,920} & \ccell{4,576} & \ccell{208} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{adjustwidth}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! As it stands there is no way the question can be answered. A minimal example is definitely needed.

Comment: agree with @egreg about the necessary example, but had the thought that if the table was defined so that cells are already in math mode, explicitly adding math mode could cause this kind of problem.

Comment: Please strip down the example to something more *minimal*. Also the class is not known. Can you replace it by a standard class?

Comment: And add missing packages (booktabs etc) and new command definitions

Comment: Sorry for my miserable attempt at an MWE. Some combination of changing \bar to \overline and putting the numbers into a \ccell (which is just a shortcut to making \multicolumn cells) seems to have worked.

Incidentally, the socsci class is the custom class provided by the journal the author is submitting to. I tried using article and had the same result.

Answer (score 2):

You need to encase the inline math terms that contain `\bar` in `\ccell` instructions. Off-topic: I'd use `\overline` rather than `\bar` to denote repeating decimals.

If you're going to align numbers in columns on their decimal markers, you would really help out your readers if most numbers actually contained decimal markers. Thus, write `0.00` rather than just `0`, and write `100.00` instead of just `100`. And, do define the column structure as `d{3.2}` instead of as `d{2.2}`.

The following compilable example uses the `article` document class since I don't know where the `socsci` document class comes from.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}% {socsci} % where might socsci.cls be found?
\usepackage{amsmath,booktabs,dcolumn,caption}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}
\newcommand\ccell[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}} % a wild guess...
\captionsetup{skip=0.5\baselineskip}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[t!]
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} % let tabular* do all the work
\caption{Network density.} 
\label{tab6}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}l*{5}{d{2.2}}} 
\toprule
Density & \ccell{$\leq 0.50$} & \ccell{$0.58\overline3$} 
        & \ccell{$0.66\overline6$} & \ccell{$0.750$} 
        & \ccell{$>0.75$} \\ 
\midrule
 & \ccell{\%} & \ccell{\%} & \ccell{\%} & \ccell{\%} & \ccell{\%} \\
\addlinespace
Disconnected & 16.27 &  0.23 &  0.00 &  0.00 &   0.00 \\
Weak         & 26.61 &  0.70 &  0.00 &  0.00 &   0.00 \\
Unilateral   & 51.45 & 51.98 & 15.76 &  2.80 &   0.00 \\
Strong       &  5.67 & 47.09 & 84.24 & 97.20 & 100.00 \\ 
\addlinespace
Total \%    & 100.00 &100.00 &100.00 &100.00 & 100.00 \\
\addlinespace
Total $n$ & \ccell{25,376} & \ccell{27,456} & \ccell{7,920} & \ccell{4,576} & \ccell{208} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

With guessing what is missing in your (not so) MWE and omitting what I see as surpluses I obtain the following table:

[image]

The code for above table is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs,makecell,multirow,tabularx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table*}[htb]
    \caption{Network density.}
\label{tab6}
    \centering
    \footnotesize
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}l*5{S[table-format=>2.4]}}%
    \toprule
Density     & \leq 0.50 &{$~~0.58\bar3$}&{$~~0.66\bar6$}& 0.750 & >0.75 \\ 
    \midrule
            & {\%}      & {\%}          & {\%}          & {\%}  & {\%}  \\
Disconnected& 16.27     & 0.23          & 0             & 0     & 0     \\
Weak        & 26.61     & 0.70          & 0             & 0     & 0     \\
Unilateral  & 51.45     & 51.98         & 15.76         & 2.80  & 0     \\
Strong      & 5.67      & 47.09         & 84.24         & 97.20 & 100   \\ 
    \midrule 
Total \%    & {100}     & {100}         & {100}         & {100} & {100} \\
Total n     & {25,376}  & {27,456}      & {7,920}       & 4,576 & 208   \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

With article document class I can't reproduce your problem.